# Access Code Authentication caching issue DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the REST API to integrate the signature integration and are planning to use Access Code authentication verification for certain signers. In our scenario the access code authenticated signer may appear more than one time in the envelope. We would assume that for each occurrence of this signer the system should challenge with a access code. However, we have seen the behavior where the user only has to enter it in the first time. It seems that the code is cached somehow and subsequent checks are bypassed. The SMS authentication behavior is working for us as expected, every time the user has to enter the code.

Any help will be appreciated.  BTW, we are testing it in demo environment.

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <allowReassign>false</allowReassign>
  <messageLock>true</messageLock>
  <brandId>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</brandId>
  <emailSubject>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</emailSubject>
  <emailBlurb>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</emailBlurb>
  <status>sent</status>
  <documents>
    <document>
      <documentId>16</documentId>
      <name>FinalContract.pdf</name>
    </document>
  </documents>
  <recipients>
    <signers>
      <signer>
        <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
        <recipientId>75</recipientId>
        <email>vendordocusign@gmail.com</email>
        <name>Signer One</name>
        <tabs>
          <signHereTabs>
            <signHere>
              <anchorString>VS1*</anchorString>
              <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset>
              <anchorYOffset>0</anchorYOffset>
              <documentId>16</documentId>
              <pageNumber>2</pageNumber>
            </signHere>
          </signHereTabs>
        </tabs>
      </signer>
      <signer>
        <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
        <recipientId>76</recipientId>
        <email>ittiyamparampath@rdacorp.com</email>
        <name>Signee Two</name>
        <tabs>
          <signHereTabs>
            <signHere>
              <anchorString>S#1</anchorString>
              <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset>
              <anchorYOffset>0</anchorYOffset>
              <documentId>16</documentId>
              <pageNumber>2</pageNumber>
            </signHere>
          </signHereTabs>
        </tabs>
        <accessCode>1234</accessCode>
      </signer>
      <signer>
        <routingOrder>3</routingOrder>
        <recipientId>77</recipientId>
        <email>ivnavin@hotmail.com</email>
        <name>Vishnu I</name>
        <tabs>
          <signHereTabs>
            <signHere>
              <anchorString>S#2</anchorString>
              <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset>
              <anchorYOffset>0</anchorYOffset>
              <documentId>16</documentId>
              <pageNumber>2</pageNumber>
            </signHere>
          </signHereTabs>
        </tabs>
      </signer>
      <signer>
        <routingOrder>4</routingOrder>
        <recipientId>78</recipientId>
        <email>ittiyamparampath@rdacorp.com</email>
        <name>Vishnu I</name>
        <tabs>
          <signHereTabs>
            <signHere>
              <anchorString>S#VP</anchorString>
              <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset>
              <anchorYOffset>0</anchorYOffset>
              <documentId>16</documentId>
              <pageNumber>2</pageNumber>
            </signHere>
          </signHereTabs>
        </tabs>
        <accessCode>1234</accessCode>
      </signer>
    </signers>
  </recipients>
  <notification>
    <useAccountDefaults>true</useAccountDefaults>
  </notification>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: Please add the JSON you are using to add your recipients and their access codes to the envelope (redact any info you don't want to include).  It might also help if you show the corresponding smsAuth that's working for you...

Comment: Added the envelope body above. Signee#2 nd 4 have the same email address. Only Signee#2 was asked to enter the access code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an account level setting that you can use to specify that a Recipient is required to authenticate each and every time they access an Envelope.  To access this setting, login to the DocuSign web console and navigate to **Preferences >> Features**, then scroll down to the "Authentication" section of that page.  If you set the "*Authenticate on return access to envelope*" setting to "***Each Access***", then I suspect you'd get the desired behavior that you've described in your question.

[image: DS Setting]

**Note**:  This is an account-level setting -- which means that it applies to all recipients for all envelopes sent via that DocuSign account.